# Is it possible for equals() to return false, even if contents of two Objects are same?

Tags: java

Is it possible for equals() to return false, even if contents of two Objects are same?
If yes, how do I prove it in the below code:
In the below example how does p1.equals(p2) result in 'false'
I know that incorrectly implemented equals() and hashcode() methods can result in this situation but wanted to know under what datasets will equality fail.

```
public class Equalitytest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person p1 = new Person("abc",12);
    Person p2 = new Person("abc",12);

//Is there any way which results in  
// assert p1.equals(p2) == false  
//What dataset will will satisfy the assertion to false?

    }

    public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.age != other.age) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 53 * hash + this.age;
        return hash;
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear how your code relates to your question.

Comment: `equals` is defined however you define it.  It just must be repeatable and be consistent with `hashCode`.

Comment: I just have a sample piece of code, my question is valid because I want to verify if equality can break if w.r.t the dataset specified.

Comment: @vmr what is your question. Its working fine.

Comment: If you want your `equals()` implementation to fail for two objects having the same content. Make `p2` an object of a class which extends `Person` and it has no attributes of its own and assign `Person p2=new  NewClass("abc",12)`.

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP your answer/comment does satisfy the criteria thanks. So if I want to prevent this from happening then I should mandatorily have 'getClass' check in 'equals' method.

Answer (score -2):

you can Override equals() method like this

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return false ;
}
```

it is legal.

Comment: Possibly you meant to have a "return false;" in there too because otherwise what you posted is so illegal that it won't even compile.